# Is there anyway I can make an if statement about an led on a button-shim being a certain color?

Tags: python, button, led, shim

I am currently making a burglar alarm for a school project. I am trying to make a button that will disable the alarm when pressed. I originally thought to have a variable change when the button shim is pressed but, while the rest of the activities in the `if` loop happen, the variable is not being changed.

My code looks like this:

```
while (check1 == 0):
    if (bE == 0): #if button E has not been pressed
        if (check() = 1): # a function that returns if there is moton
            check1 = 1
        @buttonshim.on_press(buttonshim.BUTTON_E)
        def button_e(button, pressed):
            buttonshim.set_pixel(0xff, 0x00, 0x00) #changes led to red no prob
            bE = 1 #supposed to change variable to 1 not working
            print "button e pressed" #prints out fine
        time.sleep(sleeptime) #so it's not checking constantly
    else:
        check1=1 #so it breaks out of while loop is E is pressed
```

I had already defined `check1` and `bE` as variables before this code segment.
This is not working properly and I was wondering if there is any way that I can detect if the led is red so I can make an if statement and set the variable through that?

Comment: Your code should be giving you a syntax error because the conditional express for the while needs to be something like `while (check1 == 0):`. You should describe how it doesn't work in more detail. Beyond that, defining a function in the loop and not even calling doesn't seem to make much sense.

Comment: Sorry my actual code has the ==

Comment: How do I call the function if I am defining it outside the loop? Sorry this is my first time working with python, I normally use Java so the defining is a little confusing to me, any help would be appreciated

Comment: Just define it outside (and maybe before) the loop. As long as it's in the same script, it should be callable.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm super lost. What is the code to call it?

Comment: Call it with something like `button_e(button_argument, pressed_argument)`.

Comment: Alright thank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

The syntax error in your first line might be the issue. Same with your if .statements

```
while (check1 = 0): #should be while (check1 == 0):
# rest of the code
```

Comment: Don't post comments this way if you don't have enough rep.

Comment: @martineau What should I do then?

Comment: Nothing I guess. Someone else with enough rep will likely point it out.